# how can I sort my claims array of objects by createdDate in the combineLatest and return Observable of ClaimSummaryResult?

Tags: angular

how can I sort my claims array of objects by createdDate in the combineLatest and return Observable of ClaimSummaryResult?

I added code for sorting in the map operator but then it get "***Type 'Observable<Claim[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.   Type 'Claim[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ClaimSummaryResult': pageNumber, pageSize, total, claims***" error.

```js
  export interface ClaimSummaryResult {
  pageNumber: number,
  pageSize: number,
  total: number,
  claims: Claim[]
}
  
  public claimSummarySearchResult$: Observable<ClaimSummaryResult> = combineLatest(this._claimSummarySearchResult$, this._claimProductTypes$).pipe(
    map(([claimSummarySearchResult, claimProductTypes]) => ({ claimSummarySearchResult, claimProductTypes })),
    filter(x => !!x.claimProductTypes && !!x.claimSummarySearchResult),
    map(x => x.claimSummarySearchResult.claims.sort((a, b) => (a.createdDate > b.createdDate ? -1 : 1)),
    tap(data => console.log('data', data)),
  );
  
  
  data sample:
{
  "pageNumber": 0,
  "pageSize": 100,
  "claims": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "claimNumber": "aaa",
      "createdDate": "2021-02-09T19:24:03.117"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "claimNumber": "bbb",
      "createdDate": "2021-02-09T17:35:07.803"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "claimNumber": "ccc",
      "createdDate": "2020-11-03T19:46:26.493"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "claimNumber": "ddd",
      "createdDate": "2021-02-09T19:24:03.117"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `x.claimSummarySearchResult.claims.sort((a, b) => (a.createdDate > b.createdDate ? -1 : 1))` you return an array of claims (`Claim[]`), while your functions return type is `Observable<ClaimSummaryResult>`. Change it to:

`public claimSummarySearchResult$: Observable<Claim[]> = ...`

EDIT

---

```
filter(x => !!x.claimProductTypes && !!x.claimSummarySearchResult),
map(x => {
  x.claimSummarySearchResult.claims.sort((a, b) => (a.createdDate > b.createdDate ? -1 : 1));
  return x.claimSummarySearchResult;
}),
```

Comment: I want to return Observable of ClaimSummaryResult but I want to sort claims array before I return Observable of ClaimSummaryResult which is an object with 4 properties: pageNumber 
pageSize
total
claims. I think inclusion of my sort function like what I did in the map is wrong.

Comment: Edited. In that case, you need to return the same object

Comment: I get "TS2322: Type 'Observable<{ claimSummarySearchResult: ClaimSummaryResult; claimProductTypes: ProductModel[]; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ClaimSummaryResult>'.   Type '{ claimSummarySearchResult: ClaimSummaryResult; claimProductTypes: ProductModel[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ClaimSummaryResult': pageNumber, pageSize, total, claims" error with your code

Comment: So you want to return only `claimSummarySearchResult` ? Edited

Comment: Yes which is an object with 4 properties.

Comment: Updated, please try that